# Get default timeout settings for puppeteer page

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Is there a way to retrieve the default timeout settings for a puppeteer page?

I see methods to set the timeouts through `page.setDefaultTimeout(timeout)`
 and `page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(timeout)` but I can't find how to read what the timeout values are in the [api docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagesetdefaulttimeouttimeout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the [_timeSettings](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/edb6f62824b0406df2ac383fa6836c74746ea11d/experimental/puppeteer-firefox/lib/TimeoutSettings.js#L19) variable and get the values from there:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless : false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
console.log(page._timeoutSettings.timeout());
console.log(page._timeoutSettings.navigationTimeout());
```

But, as `_timeSettings` is an internal value, nothing guarantees that Puppeteer will honor that name in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the default timeout in the description for the [`page.goto`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) function:

> Maximum navigation time in milliseconds, defaults to **30 seconds**, pass `0` to disable timeout. The default value can be changed by using the [page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(timeout)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagesetdefaultnavigationtimeouttimeout) or [page.setDefaultTimeout(timeout)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagesetdefaulttimeouttimeout) methods.

There is no official way to read the value. However, you can programmatically read the values using an undocumented API. See the answer from hardkoded on how to do it.